# how to enter value in dropdownlist(using AJAX) that is not visible in selenium by python

Tags: ajax, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Iam new to selenium and i want to enter value in dropdown list and tried with various methods and searched in web and i have seen
many posts in the STACKOVER flow nothing worked for me

this is the HTML code

i tried with

```
1)    x=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("expiry-date-month"))

       x.select_by_value("4")


2) element = driver.find_element_by_id('expiry-date-month')
    for option in element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
          if option.text=='4':
             option.click()
```

i want to Select the Month check box values when iam trying getting error message as "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" please show me a solution for this

### HTML code

```
<form id="form-credit-card" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="row-fluid"/>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid card-wrap">
<div class="row-fluid name-wrap">
<div class="row-fluid dob-wrap hide" style="opacity: 0;">
<div class="row-fluid maestro-wrap hide" style="opacity: 0;">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3 iframe expiry-wrap">
<label for="expiry-date">Expiration date</label>
<select id="expiry-date-month" class="expirydatemonth selectBox" size="1" name="expirydatemonth" style="display: none;">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<a class="selectBox expirydatemonth selectBox-dropdown selectBox-active" style="width: 30px; display: inline-block; -moz-user-select: none;" title="" tabindex="0">
<span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 0px;">Month</span>
<span class="selectBox-arrow"/>
</a>
<span class="slash">/</span>
<select id="expiry-date-year" class="expirydateyear selectBox" size="1" name="expirydateyear" style="display: none;">
<a class="selectBox expirydateyear selectBox-dropdown" style="width: 30px; display: inline-block; -moz-user-select: none;" title="" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Your first attempt, 1, would be the normal way to do this. What errors or exceptions occur when you try that?

Comment: "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" this is the error message iam getting for what ever method i use

Comment: Iam using selenium 2.37.2 and Firefox version 20

Comment: You can do it using JavascriptExecutor http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('expiry-date-month').style.displa‌​y = 'block'") time.sleep(5) try: x = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("expiry-date-month")) x.select_by_visible_text("4") print "entered text" except NoSuchElementException: print "Error",, but iam getting a new dropdown list besides that and not entering any value in it tried like this

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you need to enable display for that dropdown using JavaScript, as display is set to 'none'.

Below code should work for you:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('expiry-date-month').style.display='block';");

//Then Select required value
x=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("expiry-date-month"))

x.select_by_value("4")
```

Comment: i did like what u mentioned written code like this    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('expiry-date-month').style.display = 'block'")
    time.sleep(5)
    
    
    try:
       x = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("expiry-date-month"))
       x.select_by_visible_text("4")
       print "entered text"
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print "Error" but iam getting a new dropdown list besides that and not entering any value in it

Comment: hi..any idea about this